# Spacing and layering won't work with images and lists

Tags: css, html, layout, border

I'm learning html and css, and I'm trying to make a header with navigation buttons, but I can't get the layout to work at all. The header image has a border around it that I can't get rid of, and no matter what I do, the list with the links won't layer on top of the image. Can anyone help?

I have the code on codepen (forgive the images, they're temporary): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPxYBa

Otherwise, the code I'm using is:

```css
#header {
  position: initial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
#nav {
  position: initial;
  z-index: 30;
}
li {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-image:url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/28/58/17/orange-background_00285817.jpg)">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/58/1822357.jpg" width="1920" height="100" />
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">resume</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">about</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: By default the `body` has some margin around it. That's why your header image has a "border" around it. Fix this by adding `body { margin: 0; }` to your css.

Comment: [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ur2827k1/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is more than one solution for the menu to be on the image, you can use background-image instead but if you like to leave it like this you can for example set the nav to `position: absolute;`. for centering the menu you can set it to `left: 0;`, `right: 0;`, and `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.nav
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxrWmb

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I know this wasn't part of the question, but how would I make the header stay at the top of the window as I scroll down?

Comment: You welcome! Set the header to position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%;